# "For the way in which..."

Tags: prepositions, idioms

> ***For* the way** in which he spoke to me the last time, I will not listen to him anymore.

Is this idiomatic? Or should I formulate it as **"*By* the way** in which..." or rather simply "**The way** in which..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. Finding the right preposition is one of the most difficult tasks in English, because so many usages are arbitrary.

We would say *Because of* the way in which he spoke to me, I will not listen to him. *Because of* will work in most similar situations. Some similar sentences and the prepositions they use:

> I am angry with him *for* the way he spoke to me.
>   I am upset with him *over* the way he spoke to me.
>   I am surprised *at* the way he spoke to me.
>   I am unhappy *with* the way he spoke to me.
>   I am hurt *by* the way he spoke to me.

In all of these cases, you can substitute *because of* for the preposition in italics, without changing the meaning much.

Comment: Thanks BobRodes! You gave me a point to search from. I found that "because of" is used to express the reason, whilst "for" is mostly used to express purpose. Only in old texts, like Shakespeare or the Bible "for" had been sometimes used as casual preposition. Appreciate!

Comment: For a more formal enunciation, could **"because of"** be replaced with **"for the reason of"** in the above phrase?

Comment: No, we wouldn't use that. If you wanted to be more formal (and "because of" is already more formal), you could say "due to" instead of "because of." That would probably sound a bit pompous to most people, though.